# When using forRoot() method in a module, do we have to declare forChild() static method, too?

Tags: angular

When we create a core module, we create a `forRoot()`, `forChild` static method to prohibit providers which it provides, to be instantiated more than once. But, i am confused at `forChild()`. If the core module has a additional provider for lazy-loaded module's injector, we also have to declare a `forChild()` static method too, of course.

But, if the core module doesn't have a provider for lazy-loaded module's injector, can we have lazy-loaded module to import the core module just using `imports: [CoreModule]` not using `imports: [CoreModule.forChild()]`? Because the core module doesn't declare a provider itself, i think lazy-loaded module can import core module ordinarily.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule.forRoot(), // imports Core Module for root injector
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
}) export class AppModule { }


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule ],
  declarations: [ ButtonComponent ],
  exports:      [ ButtonComponent ],
  providers:    [] // It doesn't have a provider in itself.
}) export class CoreModule {

  // It is using forRoot() to register a provider.
  // But, it doesn't declare forChild().
  static forRoot(config: UserServiceConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: CoreModule,
      providers: [
        {provide: UserService, useClass: UserServiceImpl }
      ]
    };
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CoreModule    // imports core module not using `forChild`
  ],
  declarations: [ ],
  providers:    [ ]
}) export class LazyLoadedModule {}
```

So, my question is that it is not required to declare `forChild()` when we using `forRoot()` method?

For more detailed situation, i suggest a example similar with `RouterModule`. This module has `forRoot()` as well as `forChild`. Think about a module is like `RouterModule` but it doesn't have additional provider for lazy loaded module.

Comment: if you don't need `forChild` don't create it... I mean what's the problem? And who calls `forRoot` to be a pattern? As for me it is more like antipattern. It removes the clarity of just providing the values on each level under some factory, it is less readable, because instead of looking at injection tokens you need to dive into the code. Angular itself uses it only for `Router` (probably just to make it easier for super-beginners)

Comment: @smnbbrv Yes, it is not a pattern, accurately. It is just an alternative way to handle a module which is imported into root as well as lazy loaded child module, providing singleton service, to ensure the service instance is only one. My question is when a module is like above, can i just import the core module in a child lazy loaded module using CoreModule not using CoreModule.forChild()—ModuleWithProvider.

Comment: yes, of course... Sometimes it is enough just trying it :)

Comment: @smnbbrv Thanks, i am confused at this. Some documents in Angular suggest that core module should only be imported by root module, inserting a logic that prevents instantiating it more than once into constructor using `@SkipSelf`, `@Optional`, `throw`. But other documents suggest that the core module can be imported twice by declaring `forRoot()` method to ensure provided service should be only one. This implicitly means that the core module can be imported more than once.

Comment: well, if you still have worries, you can do a simple test: create a module with a simple service in it, add console.log to the service constructor and see how many times it is instantiated while navigating between subroutes. The reality says way more than theory :) I (personally) decided to avoid the `forRoot` things (and lazy modules) for my projects. Most of the time it does not worth it at all